# SQLITE_IOERR but the insert operation still succeeds?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm having random `SQLITE_IOERR` with Sqlite3 (Node.js under WSL).

My program makes a lot of insert operations (one after the other) and sometime there's a random `SQLITE_IOERR`. I can replicate this bug by doing a lot of `SELECT count(*) FROM mytable` from the sqlite3 command line tool.

In order to fix this, I've implemented a repeat mechanism which retries the query if it gets an `SQLITE_IOERR`. This works well except that sometime the second call fails due to a `UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT` error.

I know for sure that there's no duplicate data in what I'm inserting so the only explanation is that it happens because, despite the `SQLITE_IOERR`, the write actually succeeded.

So I'm wondering, is there any way to detect and prevent this? Basically what can I do to make sure that any `SQLITE_IOERR` actually means that there was an error and no data was inserted?

Comment: Did you check on the db if it was indeed inserted?

Comment: Good point, I've just checked and I can see it's indeed been inserted.

Comment: How about using `transactions` and if you catch an error `rollback` the changes? You can do this by `serializing`, Take a look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3-transactions) page to see more

Comment: Yes I've tried wrapping each insert in a transaction, but it seems any query including `BEGIN TRANSACTION` can fail. So it might begin the transaction, fail with ioerr on the commit (but not really), and when I try a rollback it tells me that no transaction is active (since the commit actually worked).

Comment: I/O errors can be caused by file system or hardware bugs, in which case your software cannot really do anything about it.

Comment: @CL., I'm going to assume that's indeed what it is. The file system is NTFS, combined with the WSL access layer (and the fact that, if I'm not mistaken, it's still beta software), means all kind of things can go wrong. For now I've decided to simply not do what was causing this bug (checking with the sqlite CLI tool while the app is running), since it won't happen in real world usage.